# How to convert a line into camel case?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

This picks all the text on single line after a pattern match, and converts it to camel case using non-alphanumeric as separator, remove the spaces at the beginning and at the end of the resulting string, (1) this don't replace if it has 2 consecutive non-alphanumeric chars, e.g "2, " in the below example, (2) is there a way to do everything using sed command instead of using `grep, cut, sed and tr`?

```
$ echo " hello
world
  title:  this is-the_test string with number 2, to-test CAMEL String
end! " | grep -o 'title:.*' | cut -f2 -d: | sed -r 's/([^[:alnum:]])([0-9a-zA-Z])/\U\2/g' | tr -d ' '
ThisIsTheTestStringWithNumber2,ToTestCAMELString
```

Comment: Change `[^[:alnum:]]` to `[^[:alnum:]]+` to mach one ore more non-alnum chars.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, that worked.

Comment: Try `sed -En '/.*title: *(.+)/{s//\1/;s/([^[:alnum:]]+|^)([0-9a-zA-Z])/\U\2/gp}' <<< "$text"`

Comment: yes, it worked @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, change `[^[:alnum:]]` to `[^[:alnum:]]+` to mach one ore more non-alnum chars.

You may combine all the commands into a GNU `sed` solution like

```
sed -En '/.*title: *(.*[[:alnum:]]).*/{s//\1/;s/([^[:alnum:]]+|^)([0-9a-zA-Z])/\U\2/gp}'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/OxOXeP)

**Details**

- `-En` - POSIX ERE syntax is on (`E`) and default line output supressed with `n`
- `/.*title: *(.*[[:alnum:]]).*/` - matches a line having `title:` capturing all after it up to the last alnum char into Group 1 and matching the rest of the line
- `{s//\1/;s/([^[:alnum:]]+|^)([0-9a-zA-Z])/\U\2/gp}` - if the line is matched,

  - `s//\1/` - remove all but Group 1 pattern (received above)
  - `s/([^[:alnum:]]+|^)([0-9a-zA-Z])/\U\2/` - match and capture start of string or 1+ non-alnum chars into Group 1 (with `([^[:alnum:]]+|^)`) and then capture an alnum char into Group 2 (with `([0-9a-zA-Z])`) and replace with uppercased Group 2 contents (with `\U\2`).

Comment: `echo "title:this is, a   test, , ,&" | sed -En '/.*title: *(.+)/{s//\1/;s/([^[:alnum:]]+|^|$)([0-9a-zA-Z])/\U\2/gp}'` this gives `ThisIsATest, , ,&`

Comment: @rodee Good catch, I forgot about the rest of the line that is not alphanumeric. Fixed.